# Pythonanywhere Template is not rendering on the django

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my webapp on pythonanywhere, but my template is not rendering at all, however the same code is showing just fine on my local visual studio.

i'm receiving the below error.

[image]

my views is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def Home(request):
    return render(request, 'Home.html')
```

my settings is

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Please help, what am i missing?

Comment: You are using `Templates` instead of `templates`, try renaming your folder.

Comment: Hi @Bamagujen_Bahaushe , I have made the change, but the problem is still persisting...

Comment: Check this line, inside your Template in the settings.py file `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates'),],` you are adding `,` behind `( BASE_DIR, 'Template')` Remove it now and try again.

Comment: Hi @Bamagujen_Bahaushe. Unfortunately no luck at the moment sir... If you can, can you kindly please share you github link or provide some video One-on-One help, to help me deploy please... I'm looking to deploy my python / django online and that's what i'm really struggling with.

Comment: Try [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=pythonanywhere+django&client=ms-android-transsion&prmd=visn&sxsrf=APwXEddGZT1aHpaY-wb6QUrBYVrxBV4bOw:1680600600856&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi618qO9Y_-AhXp_7sIHeXmDw0Q_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=360&bih=664&dpr=2#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:c993969c,vid:Y4c4ickks2A)